# Create object using objectFactory from list

Tags: apache-camel, mybatis, jaxb2

I'm using apache camel. I want to create Object of class Items (Items has a list of Item).

This is my route:

```
<route>
            <from uri="mybatis:getAllItems?statementType=SelectList&amp;?consumer.useIterator=false>

            <to uri="bean:objectFactory?method=createItems"/>

            <marshal>
                <jaxb contextPath="com.domain"
                      encoding="utf-8" prettyPrint="true" />
            </marshal>

            <to uri="activemq:queue:items"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
```

I get from database list of item and want to create Items from it, I have generated my class from xsd file. And my question is: "How can I create Object from list instead of one database object"?

Answer (score 0):

Is the **additional question mark** `?` after `SelectList&amp;` in the mybatis URI a typo in the question? if it is really in your code you should remove it.

```
<from uri="mybatis:getAllItems?statementType=SelectList&amp;consumer.useIterator=false>
```

Apart from that, your URI look good and it should produce a List.